# How do you add a custom jar (graph implementation) to gremlin console?

Tags: gremlin, gremlin-server

I am currently using version 3.2.0-incubating of apache-gremlin-console and I was wondering how to load a custom graph implementation. I have used the tinker graph examples to verify the console is loaded correctly. I have attempted to use the :install command to load my custom jar but I get an unresolved dependency error - Error grabbing Grapes. Is the correct way to load a custom graph jar by using the :install command? Is there another way to load an external jar and access it via the gremlin console? Or do I have implement my own console to use a custom graph implementation?

Please advise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to import your classes directly from the Gremlin Console. One thing you should look out for is making sure that Grapes can load your libraries. This is done through the `grapeConfig.xml` and you can find more discussion and examples in the [TinkerPop documentation](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.2.0-incubating/reference/#gremlin-applications).

In particular, if you're building your graph implementation with Maven, then you'd need to make sure you `mvn clean install` it into your local Maven repository. And then in the `grapeConfig.xml`, you'd need to make sure the local Maven repository is included

```
<ibiblio name="local" root="file:${user.home}/.m2/repository/" m2compatible="true"/>
```

Another tip is to enable debugging of the install command by adjusting the [`JAVA_OPTIONS`](https://github.com/apache/incubator-tinkerpop/blob/master/gremlin-console/src/main/bin/gremlin.sh#L96) in the `gremlin.sh`

```
JAVA_OPTIONS="${JAVA_OPTIONS} -Divy.message.logger.level=4 -Dgroovy.grape.report.downloads=true"
```

I'll also add that if you are creating a new TinkerPop Graph implementation, the community would love to hear from you on the [developer mailing list](https://lists.apache.org/list.html?dev@tinkerpop.apache.org).